# Speed of light not constant as measured by many scientific / research groups, but averaged & politically standardized?

Tags: politics, physics, light

In banned/ removed TEDxTalk,
[The Science Delusion - Rupert Sheldrake at TEDx Whitechapel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1TerTgDEgUE), the speaker has talked about various things but I am focused on the "constants" such as "light" that he has mentioned.

He says:

> "Speed of Light apparently as recorded has been changing since the 1920s by variations and instead of sharing this variance and Raw data around it they choose to BURY that fact by averaging & standardizing something as a constant.

Raw Scientific data vs Standardization department.

Does what he say about the experiments and variance credible or part truth, part false? I'm skeptic, but curious.

How much truth and how much not?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63691/discussion-on-question-by-alex-s-speed-of-light-not-constant-as-measured-by-many).